# Validation Error only for data in UTF-8 in h:selectOneMeny

Tags: java, validation, jsf, utf-8

There is a amazing bug in my jsf application. I create selectOneMenu component in the code

```
  private  Map<String,String> languages; //+getter
  private String language; //+getter/setter

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    languages = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    languages.put("Русский", "ru");
    languages.put("Казахский", "kz");
  }
```

and on the page

```
        <h:selectOneMenu id="language" value="#{bean.language}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{bean.languages}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
```

and after submit everything is ok.But if I change itemValue from

```
 languages.put("Русский", "ru");
```

to

```
 languages.put("Русский", "рус.язык");
```

then after submit I got **"Validation Error: Value is not valid"**. 
Why? I really don't understand.

I use jsf 2.1.7, application server - JBoss.

Comment: `рус.язык` is that a standard language-code?

Comment: no,it's a simple text. I can write any russian word(in general - not English text) in itemValue - it doesn't matter,I always got the error.